# How do I properly open a file for deletion?

Tags: c#, .net, file, delete-file

I thought this is a completely trivial task but it gave me some headache. I would like to open a file to ensure I got exclusive access, test for certain conditions, then delete it.

Right now I'm using a 99% approach:

```
FileStream s = null;
try {
    s = new FileStream (
        path,
        FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.ReadWrite,
        FileShare.None);
    // some stuff about the file is checked here
    s.Dispose ();
    // hope the file is not accessed by someone else...
    File.Delete (path);
    return true;
}
catch (IOException) {
    if (s !=null) s.Dispose ();
    return false;
}
```

This usually works, but I figured there'd be a better way that avoids the edge condition.

Opening the file with a DeleteOnClose flag does not work because said check (which occurs after opening with the deletion flag already set) might indicate that the file should not be deleted.

Comment: Not sure this will help, but have you looked at the [transactional file manager](http://transactionalfilemgr.codeplex.com/) project on codeplex?

Comment: Did you try opening the file with FileShare.Delete and call File.Delete before you dispose the stream?

Comment: What is actually the problem? The first open can throw an IOException if the file is already locked (or got deleted by someone else) just in the same way the File.Delete can. You catch and deal with the exception so where does this create a problem for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, this will always be a race condition.  There's a chance that another process may grab the file before the file is closed.  Just make sure to carefully evaluate how your program is supposed to operate if it wasn't able to delete the file.

Comment: @Fox32: Wouldn't that allow other apps to delete the file while i have it open (and on Windows, I believe, also allows writing to the file in addition)?

Comment: @Eddy: Not sure if I understand you correctly. I want to perform some checks on the file before deleting it. There is not way to simply call Delete right away.

Comment: @BryanCrosby: The program can already dead with most of the potential trouble, but I figured there'd be a clean approach. File manipulation is, after all, one of the oldest and most important tasks in programming.

Comment: @Oded: It looks nice, I'll investigate this further. However, if possible, I would like to stick to the built-in toolset of .net 4.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you don't allow write in fileShare, other application shouldn't be able to write, but to delete the file. You could try it by adding a sleep before closing the stream and delete the file in explorer.

Comment: @Fox32: Iirc Windows only differentiates between read-only and allow-everything. Write, ReadWrite, Delete etc all map to full access.

Comment: @mafutct I was on the same route as Bryan Crosby's comment. And my question is what the problem is if the File.Delete line would throw an IOException (and fail to delete the file) because some other machine/process/thread/instance got a handle to the file just before your Delete got executed.

Comment: @Eddy: Then we would enter the catch and `return false` without deleting the file. That's well defined behavior in my case.

Comment: Which is the same result as when the file is already locked by something else and you execute the " new FileStream(...)" part. In both those cases it won't delete the file and return false. So why is it a problem if you get the exception on the .Delete() call when it's not a problem on the new Filestream call?

Comment: @Eddy: The problem would arise if I open the file, check it, then close the handle, another app writes to the file (invalidating my prior check) and finally my code mistakenly deletes the file. Any other case of failure (like being unable to open the file, or another app taking control after the first Dispose) does not create trouble.

Comment: I put up a related question about the Share-Delete issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999671/does-opening-a-file-with-share-delete-allow-others-to-write

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path,
       FileMode.Open,
       FileAccess.ReadWrite,
       FileShare.Delete))
    {
        // you can read the file here and check your stuff
        File.Delete(path);
    }
```

PS: note the 'using' keyword. It allows you to have a cleaner code as it takes care of Dispose calls.

Comment: As per the comments, wouldn't that allow different apps to access the file?

Comment: @mafutrct - FileShare.Delete means "allows subsequent deleting of the file". A different app could delete it, but not write to it nor read from it.

Comment: Though in my case, having the file deleted would not be an issue. Rather having the file written to would be - I'm going to put up a different Q for that.

Comment: Makes totally sense, but (as stated in the OP comments) I fear it might not work that way (on Windows, at least).

Comment: @mafutrct - it does work that way. You can test it easily with notepad for example. 1) Create a file with notepad, add some text, save it and keep it opened. 2) Run your program that reads this file's content and waits, say, for a keyboard key (as a placeholder for your checks). 3) While the program is waiting, try to save again in notepad, you'll see it does not work because the file is locked by your program. 4) press the key and you'll see the file is sucessfully deleted. This is how it's meant to be. The only drawback as said,  is another program can delete, but you say it's not an issue.

Comment: Can something similar be done for moving the file instead of deleting?

Comment: @Jeremy - I suggest you detail your scenario in another question. There are many ways to "move a file".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're imitating "using" statement, and you're doing it the wrong way. You should Dispose the file stream just once, in the finally clause, not twice in try and catch. But, better use using.

```
using (FileStream s = new FileStream())
{
}
```

---

Second, you're best option is Transactional NTFS (one of the wrappers can be found in Nabu Library: https://dev.triflesoft.org/mercurial/nabu/), however Transactional NTFS is limited to NTFS and Windows Vista+, so if you need FAT16/FAT32 or Windows XP, this is not the way to go.

---

You can also try to move/rename opened file to disallow access by other processes, but this is limited to NTFS too AFAIR.

---

If you do not need a file to be deleted instantly, you can use Setup API's SetupQueueDelete function.

Comment: The dispose within the try is required because I cannot delete an open file.

Comment: @mafutrct use close instead of dispose then.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I don't understand how that helps. Don't Close and Dispose map to the same code for FileStream?

Comment: It is correct to use a using statement here -- however, the dispose design pattern allows it to be called multiple times.  Subsequent requests are simply ignored.  See MSDN for the explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Ah, got it, yes. Could you add a complete code example with `Close` and a (single) `if != 0 { Dispose }` to your answer for reference?

Comment: @mafutrct For FileStream, yes. But doing what you are doing is a bad design pattern habit to get in to. Not all classes that implement both Close and Dispose act the same (SqlConnection for example). It is just a better habit to have.

Comment: I deleted my old comment mafutrct responded to as it was wrong after looking in reflector. So i deleted it and reworded it.

Comment: @BryanCrosby: Yeah, that's why I did it that way in the first place. Though using+Close seems more clean and easy to read and understand here. (but Dispose twice is technically not a mistake)

Answer (score 0):

You can't totally prevent the possibility of the race condition. Considering that your program is in trouble if between the check and the delete the file gets modified there are at least 2 workarounds I can see:

- Get a temp file name, rename the file to the tempfile, do the check and rename back if needed (could lead to new issues depending on your business logic)
- You could set the readonly attribute on the file before you check it.