# Does opening a file with Share-Delete allow others to write?

Tags: windows, file, fileshare

The FileShare enumeration offers various flags such as Read, Write, Delete, ... . Normally I'd think that sharing a file for deletion only allows deletion but nothing else (like reading).

However, I remotely recall that Windows only differentiates between read-only and full access to files, so actually sharing for deletion allows writing to the file as well. Sadly this is from many years back and I neither found the original source nor any related info. Is there a reliable spec on the actual behavior? Is it dependent on the OS or the FS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the [CreateFile Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> FILE_SHARE_DELETE: 
>   Enables subsequent open operations on a file or
>   device to request delete access. Otherwise, other processes cannot
>   open the file or device if they request delete access. If this flag is
>   not specified, but the file or device has been opened for delete
>   access, the function fails. Note  Delete access allows both delete and
>   rename operations.

The documentation doesn't mention that read access is allowed, too.